# Salesforce functionality limited by Docusign Plan

Tags: docusignapi

Testing out the platform I was running on both a developer account and a Trial Business Pro account until I purchased a standard plan.

Up until I purchased the standard plan, envelope statuses would update by the second and the functionality built with the Apex Toolkit was working well.

Once changing to the standard paid plan, envelopes statuses take 10-15 minutes to update and some functionality is not working.

My question is:

1. Do the different plans have different status updating times in Salesforce?
2. Is functionality of the Apex Toolkit limited between the different plans?
3. Does the Connect option (which is missing now) have anything to do with the above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. They do not. Writeback to Salesforce takes place via DocuSign Connect. Some plans don't support Connect out of the box but the actual writeback times / delays do not differ between account plan types.
2. Indirectly, the only way that a plan type can interfere with an API call that worked on another plan type is if it had entitlement to a feature that your new plan does not, IE: The ability to allow Comments, to set recipient signing language, to set envelopeID Stamp Control, etc...
3. I would highly suspect that it does -- in fact I'm a little surprised that your writebacks are happening at all if you don't have Connect enabled. Salesforce adds an object reference IE: Opportunity / AccountIds to the envelope's custom fields on send. When Connect sees these fields, it knows to write back to that specific object. Without Connect enabled and configured it shouldn't be able to process these writebacks at all.

I think you should have a conversation with your Account Rep first regarding Connect entitlement, then you can reconnect your Salesforce instances to the updated DocuSign account which is something that we can help you with.

Regards,

Matt